# Why can't I call later-defined sub in BEGIN block even with forward declaration?

Tags: perl

This works:

```
use strict;
X("xxxxxx");
sub X { print shift;}
```

This produces an error:

```
use strict;
BEGIN {
    X("xxxxxx");
}
sub X { print shift;}
```

Error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::X called at ./test.pl line 5.
```

This makes sense, since we are in the middle of compile phase when executing the sub... so the compiler didn't get to the sub declaration/definition yet.

... BUT: **Adding a forward declaration (before BEGIN block or inside it) doesn't help**:

```
use strict;
sub X;
BEGIN {
    X("xxxxxx");
}
sub X { print shift;}
```

Why doesn't the forward declaration work when the function is called in the BEGIN block? I would assume that it takes place during compile phase, the way `my` declaration does.

`perldoc perlsub` doesn't seem to shed any light.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `BEGIN` block is *executed as soon as it has been parsed*. This means that perl has'nt seen the definition of the sub yet<sup>1</sup>. Your only solution is to define the function before it's used:

```
sub foo { print shift }
# When the parser reaches this point, the "foo" sub has been compiled

BEGIN {
    # Ergo, "foo" can be used here
    foo("xxx");
}
# The BEGIN block is executed once the parser arrives here
```

You could also choose a phaser that's executed later, e.g. `INIT`:

```
INIT {
    foo("xxx");
}

sub foo { print shift }
```

`BEGIN` and friends are documented in [`perldoc perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END)

---

1. A pre-declaration like `sub foo;` only provides guidance for the parser in the context of prototypes, and the bareword vs. subroutine call disambiguation. It does not make the parser jump forward to the actual definition. The subroutine stub generated by a predeclaration is not actually callable.

Comment: I'm using BEGIN to avoid loading a bunch of modules before an early fork is executed (in that BEGIN block). So `INIT` won't work, unfortunately

Comment: @DVK `fork` inside `BEGIN` is a horrible prospect. You could also delay compilation for some parts using `eval "string"` or `require`, but that also has its issues.

Comment: @ikegami - duh. That's EXACTLY why I can't use `INIT` to contain the fork block - if I do, then subsequent `use` ones will execute before the fork/

Comment: @ikegami - For some reason I had this mental picture that the compile process would short-circuit to the sub definition because of forward declaration.