# Why is "fork inside BEGIN ... a horrible prospect" in Perl?

Tags: perl, fork

As part of a comment on another SO Q&A, a user noted that:

> fork inside BEGIN is a horrible prospect

Why is that a "horrible prospect"? (on a technical level - let's leave aside readability or prettiness of design)

```
use strict;
BEGIN {
    # Begin block to fork off a child process.
    # This is done in BEGIN, because otherwise My::HeavyModule module
    # will be loaded BEFORE the fork and thus inherited by child process
    # which is something we want to avoid

    my $init = 1; # Some lightweight init code

    if (my $pid = fork()) {
        # Nothing to do here, proceed to the rest of the main program
    } else {
        die "cannot fork" unless defined $pid;
        print "Child process started!\n";
        exit 0;
    }
} # End BEGIN block

use My::HeavyModule; # Very heavyweight on both startup time and memory 

# Start parent process logic using My::HeavyModule;
```

Just to be clear: **I am *NOT* asking if there are better ways to achieve what this code is doing**. I'm asking why this approach was called "horrible", NOT whether it can be replaced by something that may be better.

Comment: Why not optionally load My::HeavyModule at runtime if in the parent process with Class::Load or something similar?

Comment: Could you post link to the comment?

Comment: @mpapec : [Here is the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22693557/133939)

Comment: @DVK : What's stopping you from using `INIT` followed by `require My::HeavyModule;`?

Comment: I agree that it doesn't sound clean. You are after all *compiling* and BEGIN is mainly used to steer compilations. It might be better to have My::HeavyModule have some initialization logic as to whether or not it loads or delays for it's heavy lifting. However, I exec in my BEGIN blocks in a number of cases (say I'm using Cygwin perl to call a Win32 GUI process, because of some issues with Strawberry x64 Windows code, I specify `use WinGUI`, which checks to see which perl is executing and then execs the proper `perl` on top of it. I always get the perl that won't blow up for a given task.)

Comment: @Zaid - there's tons of heavy modules. It's easier to encapsulate the fork than to re-do existing code to use require. The point of the question isn't how to NOT do fork in BEGIN, though - it's "why is it a bad idea that I need to do something else like INIT+require in the first place". IOW, I'm asking "Why shouldn't I do X" and you are instead asking me "Why do you want to do X instead of Y". Whether Y is a better idea or not is irrelevant to assessing whether X is a good idea or not.

Comment: ... "You can do it another way" isn't really a good reason to declare something to be "horrible".

Comment: so why is the child even the same program, if you don't want it to use the same modules and it is exiting before the rest of the script is even compiled?  sounds to me like what you actually want is to fire off a child perl running a different script.

Comment: @ysth - guilty. The reason it's in the same program is non-technical (company politics). That's a hard requirement I can't escape.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote the following comment which you are referring to:

> `fork` inside `BEGIN` is a horrible prospect. You could also delay compilation for some parts using `eval "string"` or `require`, but that also has its issues.

although not because of technical reasons (there are none beyond what [dan1111 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22694557/1521179), and an [explicit portability warning in `perlfork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html#BEGIN-blocks)), but because it completely broke my expectations about any programs behaviour.

- Each piece of code has a *compile time*. I expect that packages and classes will be set up here, and maybe that some metaprogramming takes place.
- Then, there is a *run time* during which the main control flow of our program occurs, during which the job of this program is being carried out.

Perl complicates this simple distinction in that one block's compile time is another block's run time (e.g. via `BEGIN` or `use` or `eval` or `require`). But there is always a clear reference point: The phase of `$0`, the program originally being invoked (see also [`${^GLOBAL_PHASE}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%7b%5eGLOBAL_PHASE%7d)). There will always be cases where it *is* a good idea to do funky things during the main script's compile time, but this doesn't necessitate that doing so would be a best practice – on the contrary, and thus my objection that doing so would be a “horrible prospect”.

If the main job of your program is to kick off two other independent programs, it might look like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pid = fork;
if (not defined $pid) {
    die "welp, can't fork: $!";
}
if ($pid) {
    exec $^X, "heavy_program_you_intended_to_be.pl", @ARGV;
}
else {
    ... # background yourself, etc.
    exec $^X, "light_program_you_intended_to_kick_off.pl";
}
```

But it would not fork in a `BEGIN`. I think this is one of many examples where you *can* do something with Perl, but this doesn't mean you *should*.

Answer (score 5):

1. You are running a process of your program before you even know if the whole thing compiles successfully.    That doesn't seem to be the type of thing you should want to do.
2. Readability.
3. Prettiness of design.

(Sorry, I know you said to ignore those last two.  But that isn't really fair, is it?  Both are very important considerations in whether code is a "horrible prospect".)

On the other hand, I love that you can do ill-advised things like this in Perl.  And I'm not going to tell you you need to re-write your code.  That depends too much on the situation: how mission-critical is this code?  How maintainable does it need to be?  How many other developers will work on it?  etc.