# Perl - Call subroutine of main namespace from package

Tags: perl, namespaces, package, subroutine

**program.pl**

```
Use Mypackage;

sub test{

print "from test";

}
```

**Mypackage.pl**

```
Package Mypackage;

::test();
```

This return nothing.

I see several threads about call subroutine in namespace from package, but I want to do **the contrary**

Print a subroutine in package from main namespace  (program.pl)

**is this possible ?**

Comment: Try to put `BEGIN {}` around the sub def and move it before the `use Mypackage` statement

Comment: Your package declaration is wrong. Perl's keywords are case sensitive. It's `package`, not `Package`.

Comment: @Hakon, I get: Undefined subroutine &main::test   not work.

Comment: Also, `use` should be lowercase, and `Mypackage` should have extension `pm`, not `pl`.

Comment: @Thenothing Ok, please update the question and show the new code. It works for me.

Comment: Your are right, can you please explain why this work before the (use) and do like answer, to accept. Thanks.

Comment: [Crossposted to PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1212680).

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  While it is certainly possible, it may be that there is a more standard approach to the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement `use Mypackage` is [equivalent to](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)

```
BEGIN { require Mypackage; Mypackage->import( ); }
```

So we see that the `Mypackage` is executed before the execution of the main program (since it is in a `BEGIN` block). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22693557/2173773) answer for more information an another example. Hence the sub `test()` in the main program is not yet defined at this time. To make it work, we 
need to have it defined when `Mypackage` is run. One way to do that is to 
put it in a `BEGIN` block before the `use Mypackage` statement in the main program.

```
BEGIN {
    sub test{
        print "from test\n";
    }
}    
use Mypackage;
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, is this possible to do in form of OOP ?,  I want to call of subroutine in syntax of OO.

Comment: @Thenothing for an object oriented call, you need an object to call your method on. There's no object in this context, and your `main` namespace wouldn't typically be a class.

Comment: @Hakon, sorry but this aproach does not work with plackup program.psgi but if work with perl program.psgi, in plack I get Undefined subroutine &main::test

Comment: @Thenothing Sorry I am not familiar with plackup. Maybe you should post a new question showing the specific code you are using?